# Test if a variable is instance of List regardless of type

Tags: apex, list, instance, type

How to test if a variable `obj` is instance of a list regardless of the type that list is holding

I have tried

```
obj instanceof List
obj instanceof List<>
```

But I'm getting a compile error

Comment: Why do you even need to know?

Comment: @AdrianLarson working on an Apex framework so late days, I push the limits of the Apex language....

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more interesting and might even garner upvotes if you make it more specific...

Comment: Sounds like it could be interesting. Do share

Comment: Be careful to [avoid spurious edits](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/spurious-edits). I've noticed you making trivial edits to a few of your posts recently. This post actively needs editing as mentioned above in the comments...perhaps try adding more substantive content.

Comment: @AdrianLarson okay sorry, my English is not that good, I rephrase sometime my Q or A, I'll try to avoid that, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved that

To test if a variable is a list regardless of the type of its elements

```
obj instanceof List<Object>
```

Comment: haha nice, seems like finding the solution was faster for you than typing the question.

Comment: Mark it as solved, benahm, so others can find it too!